# Error using String(format: , args) with SwiftUI in Xcode11 Beta 4

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcode11

After upgrading to Xcode 11 Beta 4, I starting seeing an error when using `String(format: , args)` with `@State` property.  See code below.  Second `Text` line throws an error:

> Expression type 'String' is ambiguous without more context

while `Text`s 1, 3, and 4 work just fine.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var selection = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My selection \(selection)") // works
            Text("My selection \(String(format: "%02d", selection))") // error
            Text("My selection \(String(format: "%02d", Int(selection)))") // works
            Text("My selection \(String(format: "%02d", $selection.binding.value))") // works
        }
    }
}
```

I realize this is Beta software, but was curious if anyone can see a reason for this behavior or is this simply a bug.  If this can't be explained, I'll file a radar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In beta 4, the property wrapper implementation changed slightly. In beta 3, your View was rewritten by the compiler as:

```swift
internal struct ContentView : View {
  @State internal var selection: Int { get nonmutating set }
  internal var $selection: Binding<Int> { get }
  @_hasInitialValue private var $$selection: State<Int>
  internal var body: some View { get }
  internal init(selection: Int = 2)
  internal init()
  internal typealias Body = some View
}
```

while on Beta 4, it does this:

```swift
internal struct ContentView : View {
  @State @_projectedValueProperty($selection) internal var selection: Int { get nonmutating set }
  internal var $selection: Binding<Int> { get }
  @_hasInitialValue private var _selection: State<Int>
  internal var body: some View { get }
  internal init(selection: Int = 2)
  internal init()
  internal typealias Body = some View
}
```

Now I am guessing: this change makes it more difficult for the compiler to infer the type of your variable? Note that another alternative that does work, is helping the compiler a little, by casting `selection as Int`:

```swift
Text("My selection \(String(format: "%02d", selection as Int))")
```

Comment: Does this warrant filing a radar?

Comment: Good question. I guess it cannot hurt, can it?

Comment: I filed the feedback with apple.  We'll see what happens, if they respond, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

**Update (Xcode 11.2)**

I also get the error:

`'inout Path' is not convertible to '@lvalue Path'`

with this code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var selection = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(format: "%d", selection)) // does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Solved by and adding the `$` prefix and then accessing `wrappedValue` in `String(format:, args:)`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var selection = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(format: "%d", $selection.wrappedValue)) // works
        }
    }
}
```