# Cannot assign to property: '$text' is immutable

Tags: swiftui

I wanted to make a custom textfield in SwiftUI to can handle first responder but I had this error in the code and struct is immutable I don't know what should I do?

```
struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @Binding var text: String
    var didBecomeFirstResponder = false

    init(txt: Binding<String>) {
        self.$text = txt
    }

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        text = textField.text ?? ""
    }

}

@Binding var text: String
var isFirstResponder: Bool = false

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) -> UITextField {
    let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
    textField.delegate = context.coordinator
    return textField
}

func makeCoordinator() -> CustomTextField.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(txt: $text)
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomTextField>) {
    uiView.text = text
    if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try `self._text = txt`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In beta 4, the implementation of property wrappers changed.

Until beta 3, this was valid:

```swift
   self.$text = txt
```

In beta 4, it changed to:

```swift
   self._text = txt
```

Check for the difference in implementation, in this other question I posted:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57088052/7786555

And for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56975728/7786555